# Faster mini Arduino board for OLED display

Tags: arduino, display

im looking to create a car live-data display gauge.
Such things as Boost, AFR, some temperatures.

For that i want to use this OLED display:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/I2C-2-42-128x64-Graphic-OLED-Yellow-Display-Arduino-PIC-Multi-wii-/201468080188?hash=item2ee86ef03c:g:Rc4AAOSw5ZBWQxoj

But since i need to update it quite frequently, i think i would need a faster Arduino than the Arduino Mini V3 one i have (Or the ATtiny i've used to work with). I was looking at the Cortex M3 arduino board, one like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-Arduino-IDE-kompatibles-Board-STM32-STM32f103C8T6-ST-ARM-32-bit-Cortex-M3-/272501782722?hash=item3f725f38c2:g:li4AAOSw241YZK24

Will it be enough for a real-time data display?
Basically all it will do is read sensors and display data, i just want to eliminate the lagginess and make it more real-time.

Thank you,
Max.

Comment: Why wouldn't an ATTiny work? http://www.instructables.com/id/ATTiny85-connects-to-I2C-OLED-display-Great-Things/

Comment: @gre_gor  OP implies in his post -- then comments -- that he'll need other sensors as well,   Might need more pins and ADCs than that tiny package offers.

Comment: ATtiny, given that it is a very compact and easy to setup chip would have too few I/O pins. It did work perfectly before in projects where i need fewer I/O's, but this time i am more concerned about the refresh rate of the display with the Atmel chips. I am thinking if going ARM Cortex way would be faster for display refresh times.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be surprised at how fast a well-programmed 16 Mhz microcontroller can be.  In this project you're taking on, which is ambitious, I suspect the least of your problems will be speed or latency of the Arduino.  Pick a micro with the *features* you need based on the sensors you've selected, after reading their datasheets.

Comment: The sensors are either 0-5V sensors or resistance type ones. So its just a matter of analog-reading all of them. Since the display i have chosen is 128x64 pixels, i had a thought that the old Arduino Nano V3 would be a little slow updating it in real-time. So you are saying that the refresh speed will not be drastically different? If so, i might aswell try it with the Arduino i have :)

Comment: I'm making no predictions -- but I always choose the microcontroller part for a design based on actual needs, including pin count.  What is the interface to your OLED?  That may drive your decision.

Comment: It's I2C, so it does not need a lot of pins to run.

Comment: From I2C.info:  "I2C bus is popular because it is simple to use, there can be more than one master, only upper bus speed is defined and only two wires with pull-up resistors are needed to connect almost unlimited number of I2C devices."  I think you need to review your part datasheets and map your various IO pins to Arduino pins and see.  This is the first step in embedded development -- designing what is connected where on a target device.  Let's say you have three other analog sensors, that's three more analog pins.  Five pins total.  Add a diagnostic LED.  That's six.  Still maybe doable.

Comment: Im ok with the I/O, did design custom circuits with Arduino or a simple ATtiny in them. Just curious if the speed i am aiming at will be enough with the Atmel chips or should i go ARM Cortex from the start.